# generic adapter to show realm data

Tags: android, realm

i am trying to create generic adapter to show realm data on `RecyclerView` but i am getting following compile time error

> Error:(25, 8) error: SearchListAdapter is not abstract and does not
>   override abstract method
>   onBindViewHolder(SearchListAdapter.SearchListViewHolder,int) in Adapter

i have two classes i.e. `ObservationInfo` and `CallReasonInfo` derived from `RealmObject`

usage to access adapter is as following

*to access observation info*

```
RealmResults<ObservationInfo> observationInfos = realm.where(ObservationInfo.class).equalTo("productCategory",lookupValue).findAll();
            adapter = new SearchListAdapter(observationInfos,lookupType);
            rvSearchItemListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

*to access CallReason info*

```
RealmResults<CallReasonInfo> callReasonInfos = realm.where(CallReasonInfo.class).equalTo("callStatusName",lookupValue).findAll();
                adapter = new SearchListAdapter(callReasonInfos,lookupType);
                rvSearchItemListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

here is my code

```
public class SearchListAdapter <E extends RealmResults>  extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SearchListAdapter.SearchListViewHolder> {


    private E lookupInfo;
    private String lookupType;
    public  SearchListAdapter(E resultInfo, String lookupType) {    
        this.lookupType = lookupType; 
        this.lookupInfo  = resultInfo;
    }   

    @Override
    public SearchListViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.seach_list_item, parent, false);

        SearchListAdapter.SearchListViewHolder viewHolder = new SearchListAdapter.SearchListViewHolder(v);

        return viewHolder;

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(SearchListViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.bind(lookupInfo.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return lookupInfo==null ? 0 : lookupInfo.size();
    }

    public class SearchListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView tvItemName;

        public SearchListViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            tvItemName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvItemName);


        }

        public void bind(RealmModel item){



            tvItemName.setText(((ObservationInfo)item).getObservationName());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @EpicPandaForce can you help here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class SearchListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
```

This should be a static inner class

```
public static class SearchListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
```

---

Also, I think this is wrong:

```
public class SearchListAdapter <E extends RealmResults>  extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SearchListAdapter.SearchListViewHolder> {    
    private E lookupInfo;
```

Should be

```
public class SearchListAdapter<E extends RealmModel>  extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SearchListAdapter.SearchListViewHolder> {    
    private RealmResults<E> lookupInfo;
```

---

But I'm a bit skeptical about this because it doesn't handle changes in the Realm, it doesn't add nor remove `RealmChangeListener`, so I'd rather just use the generic RecyclerView.Adapter for RealmResults that Realm provides:

https://github.com/realm/realm-android-adapters

Added as

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'io.realm:android-adapters:1.4.0'
}
```

Using

```
public class SearchListAdapter<E extends RealmModel>  extends RealmRecyclerViewAdapter<E, SearchListAdapter.SearchListViewHolder> {
    public SearchListAdapter(Context context, RealmResults<E> results) {
         super(context, results, true);
    }
```

---

EDIT: To make the view holder generic, you need to add a generic parameter to it.

```
public class SearchListAdapter<E extends RealmModel>  extends RealmRecyclerViewAdapter<E, SearchListViewHolder<E>> {
    // ...

}

public abstract class SearchListViewHolder<E extends RealmModel> extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public SearchListViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
    }

    public abstract void bind(E e);
}
```

Comment: in my `bind` function how would i dynamically get the fields pertaining to specific calss ? like for `observationInfo` i  have different methods to fetch values and for `callReasonInfo` i have different methods.`public void bind(RealmModel item){



            tvItemName.setText(((ObservationInfo)item).getObservationName());
        }`